# PostgreSQL memory cost of Transition Tables

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Simple question (I think!)

They've been available since pg10, but I only recently discovered [transition tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-TRANSITION-EXAMPLE) yesterday. Essentially they allow you to convert row-level triggers into a single statement-level trigger. It's great! I tried this [example from EDB](https://mktgsite.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/can-modified-tuples-be-accessed-using-statement-level-trigger-postgres), then came up with my own and indeed I can see the performance boost.

Before I go crazy and modify all my applicable triggers, I'm just wondering about these `REFERENCING` tables that are now available in the trigger. Are they "free"? As in, is postgres just exposing something that was already existing in memory? Or are they actually proportionally expensive to your batch size and could require higher `work_mem` values to offset the time gain from calling fewer triggers?

I should probably test this myself by inspecting memory consumption with and without these transition tables. But if anyone knows the answer off-hand that'd be great!

Comment: It's in the documentation for much longer, version 8.0 (released in 2005): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/plpgsql-trigger.html And nothing comes for free, everything has its cost and takes time. Depends on your situation how much

Comment: @FrankHeikens Where do you see transition tables in the 8.0 documentation?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe see the examples

Comment: @FrankHeikens You must be mixing something up. This is not about the `OLD` and `NEW` row in a row level trigger. See the [release notes for v10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/release-10.html#id-1.11.6.28.5.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows for transition tables are stored in memory and spill to disk if the transition table gets too large. So transition tables consume resources on the database server. Still, it can be more efficient than a trigger function call per row.

Comment: So you are confirming that transition tables basically clone modified data in memory, and they're not some magical symbolic link towards an existing stack of data about to be committed? That was my assumption too.

Just confirming -- there is no way to pre-emptively filter these transition tables right? As in selectively append with a filter?

Comment: No, they are just the collected old or new data.